# Two-way data binding Converter

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, two-way-binding

I'm trying to use a converter from CharArray to String for my `password` two-way databinding field.

```
var password = ObservableField<CharArray>()
```

Following the [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#converters) :

```
public class Converter {
    @InverseMethod("stringToCharArray")
    public static String charArrayToString(
            ClearableEditText view,
            char[] oldValue,
            char[] value
    ){
        return value.toString();
    }

    public static char [] stringToCharArray(
            ClearableEditText view,
            String oldValue,
            String value
    ){
        return value.toCharArray();
    }
}
```

In XML file I used it like this :

```
android:text="@={Converter.charArrayToString(viewModel.password)}"
```

But I still got the bellow exception :

```
error: Could not find inverse method: public static char[] stringToCharArray(ClearableEditText, char[], java.lang.String)
    public static String charArrayToString(
                         ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work fine for me, maybe after restarting AS  :

```
public class Converter {
    @InverseMethod("toCharArray")
    public static String toString(char [] value) {
        if(value == null) return "";
        return value.length == 0 ? "" : String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static char [] toCharArray(String value) {
        if(value == null) return "".toCharArray();
        return value.isEmpty() ? "".toCharArray() : value.toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `BindingAdapter` and `InverseBindingAdapter` for two way data binding. Try using below Binding adapter.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void bindArrayInText(TextView view, char[] value) {
    view.setText(String.valueOf(value));    
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static char[] getArrayFromText(TextView view) {
    String value = view.getText().toString();

    return value.toCharArray();;
}
```

And use like

```
android:text="@={viewModel.password}"
```

Comment: @Chulo, Have you checked?

Comment: Sorry, I don't wont to use this approach. but any way I got the Converter to work. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the converter, so that I can learn from that?

Comment: check my answer.